# Why can't I use rand() with the size of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I am trying to generate a number between 0 and the size of an array.
There is my code but the output is always 2.
Edit: I tried with another compiler and the output was only 7
Please help me.

There is my full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int main (){

    string motMystere = ("Bonjour");
    int tailleMotMystere (0);
    vector<string> motMelange;
    tailleMotMystere= motMystere.size();
    srand(time(0));
    int nombreRandom = 0;
    
    nombreRandom = rand() % tailleMotMystere;
    cout << motMystere.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even this chain of numbers can be random: 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2. Maybe you simply have bad luck

Comment: Since this is tagged C++ I'd recommend you look into using [C++ random features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random)

Comment: Are you calling `srand` every time before you call `rand`? I can't tell because this is not a [mcve]. If you are you should not.

Comment: @c_kusanagi can you please provide the entire code (if you are looping and calling rand(), please include that as well.)

Comment: Based on the code you provided, you shouldn't be getting repeated result. However, if you have put them into some kind of loops, it's possible that you have structured your loop wrong.

Comment: That it is the entire code. I am not looping or doing anything else. You can try to compile it on your end and see what hapens.

Answer (score 2):

You will get a new random number every new second you run the program (since you use `time()` to seed the pseudo random number generator), but you are not printing the random number, you are printing the length of `motMystere`, so change

from

```
cout << motMystere.size() << endl;
```

to

```
cout << nombreRandom << endl;
```

---

Note that using `srand()` and `rand()` is discouraged since C++11. Use the new [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) classes and functions.

Example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

int main (){
    std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}()); // A seeded PRNG

    std::string motMystere  = "Bonjour";
    size_t tailleMotMystere = motMystere.size();
    
    // Distribution: [0, tailleMotMystere)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(0, tailleMotMystere - 1);
    
    size_t nombreRandom = dist(prng);
    std::cout << nombreRandom << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I keep doing the same thing over and over and I keep getting the same result -- what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you are calling `srand` every time before you call `rand()`

```
srand(time(0));
int nombreRandom = 0;

nombreRandom = rand() % tailleMotMystere;
```

Instead you should call `srand` **once** at the beginning of your program.

Comment: @john small clarification, OP is calling the rand() function only once, so what's your intention behind asking this ```" every time before you call rand() "```?

Comment: @SaiSreenivas It's implied by the question and the code that the OP has some kind of loop containing the posted code. If they did not they wouldn't be asking this question.